# Would a Sorcerer roll damage once or twice when Twinning a damaging (non-attack) spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, damage, metamagic

There is a useful rule in the PHB concerning multiple creatures being damaged simultaneously (PHB, p. 196):

> If a spell or other effect deals damage to more than one target at the same time, roll the damage once for all of them.

That's a handy rule that stops us from needing to roll damage dozens of times for a single fireball. But it got me thinking about the Sorcerer's *twinned-spell* metamagic (PHB, p. 102).

> When you cast a spell that targets only one creature and doesn’t have a range of self, you can spend a number of sorcery points equal to the spell’s level to target a second creature in range with the same spell (1 sorcery point if the spell is a cantrip).

It has been clarified elsewhere that [you aren't casting a second spell](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/64224/30218), but rather including an additional target in the effect of the original spell. And while it's been established that the attacks from a twinned spell with attack rolls don't happen simultaneously ([specifically in the case of *Booming Blade*](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/144020/30218)), it seems less clear to me that this would be the case for spells with no attack roll.

**So if a spell like *Blight* were twinned, would you only roll once for the damage** and use that total for both targets (modified by their respective saving throws), **or would you roll damage twice (once for each target)** because the original version of the spell only targeted one creature?

Comment: Related: [How many times do you roll damage for Magic Missile?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/109764/how-many-times-do-you-roll-damage-for-magic-missile), and [How many attack/damage rolls does a sorcerer make when using the Twinned Spell metamagic option?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/48935/how-many-attack-damage-rolls-does-a-sorcerer-make-when-using-the-twinned-spell-m)

Comment: Heh. I swear I searched for this question before I posted it, but somehow missed it! Thanks @Rykara : that second one definitely answers the question.